# How to insert a PHP 'while loop' into JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to display the values of an SQL table in a D3 map for each US state. Below is code excerpts from my `file.php`:

1. Here is the SQL query:

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT COUNT(State) FROM `mytable`";
   $sql_result= mysqli_query($cnx,$sql) or die('Could not execute' . mysqli_error()) ;
   ```
2. Here is how I pass the result into an array

   ```
    <? while($myvar=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) { **need to add both php and javascript below..**  }

   <?php $js_array = json_encode($myvar['0']);?>
   ```
3. Here is where I need to pass the data:

   ```
   .forEach(function(d){ 
       var     kpi01=<?php echo "var nbcustomers = ". $js_array . ";\n";?>, //  No of customers in that state
               kpi02= .....

               sampleData[d]={kpi01, kpi02}; 
       });
   ```

Can anyone help me with suggestions to properly insert the JavaScript code after the `while` loop within the `.forEach`?

Comment: you cannot do in .js file but can be done in .php or .html files

Comment: You'll need to use an AJAX call to a PHP file that handles the server side processing you need.  PHP runs server side and runs BEFORE JavaScript, which runs client side.

Comment: Sidenote: your sql query is kind of pseudo to me (missing a quote) and that mysqli_error function requires db connection as an argument.

Comment: Hi Fred:  I haven't displayed full code because I know it is not the issue :)

Comment: **Still have not got the time to refactor your code for you**. And in this **version** of your question you do not even give the potential answerer any idea how complicated a good answer would be

Comment: ok Samantha, I added the missing quote in an edit since it was throwing off syntax highlighting ;-) details details, eh? lol I'm just a perfectionist that way.

Comment: @RiggsFolly : yes I have reworked it since last time! Do you agree with the suggestion of using an AJAX call? :)

Comment: Yes that would be my solution. But thats not necessarily an easy solution either

Comment: I feel better at least that I am not the only one to find this difficult! :)

Comment: Just use an AJAX call and pull in JSON data. There's no reason to inline all this junk in the middle of some JavaScript code. Keep your PHP and JavaScript concerns as separated as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess around with trying to generate a bunch of variables with numbers in their names.

Just construct the data structure you need (an array of your SQL query results) in PHP, then use `json_encode` to convert it to JavaScript.

```
 <?php
     $my_array = [];
     while($myvar=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
         $my_array[] = $myvar;
     }
     $js_array = json_encode($my_array);
 ?>
 <script>
 var javascript_array = <?php echo $js_array; ?>;
 </script>
```